# defined ('ABSPATH') false after AJAX post to other PHP-file

Tags: php, plugin-development, jquery, ajax, wp-admin

I'm new to Wordpress so please be gentle.

I succesfully created a Admin submenu page. The submenu page itself is supposed to show a list of files that are in 'wp-admin/whatever/myFolder' with buttons attached and it does. Here is a button example:

```
<li>$file</li><input type='button' value='choose' data-filename='$file' data-path='$fullPath' name='choose' />
```

I $_POST the data to the file "myPost.php" on click, using AJAX with jQuery like the following in the same .php file that creates my submenu:

```
        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '../wp-content/plugins/myPlugin/myPost.php',
        data: {
            fileName : $(this).data('filename'), 
            filePath  : $(this).data('path'), 
        },
        success:function(data) {
            console.log(data); 
        },
        error: function(errorThrown){
            console.log(errorThrown);
        }
    });
```

The POST works flawlessly.
The problem I'm facing is, that the "myPost.php" file can't execute further Wordpress functions like "add_action" or which ever, because the defined ('ABSPATH') at the beginning of "myPost.php" is always false.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: in WordPress, it's better to not access file directly with AJAX request but use AJAX like that : https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps and you should be good to go:-

1. Localize your script where you are implementing
   ajax(https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script)
2. Then make use of wp_ajax_{myfunction} (admin) and wp_ajax_nopriv_{myfunction}
3. And lastly implement your code inside that function

   ```
   myfunction(){
       /****Your code goes here*****/
   }
   ```

   Eg. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17855846/using-ajax-in-a-wordpress-plugin